# Javascript progress bar in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, progress-bar

I'm implementing a feature like Instagram story in react native, where I need to implement a progress bar on top to indicate the progress of current story. 
Currently I have a timer that start count once the story start playing:

```
onStart = (timeout: number, total: number) => {
    const updateFrequncy = 1000 / PROGRESS_BAR_TICK;
    this._timer = this.props.setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            progress:
                state.progress +
                (PROGRESS_BAR_SPEED * PROGRESS_BAR_RANGE * updateFrequncy) /
                    total,
        }));
    }, PROGRESS_BAR_TICK);
};
```

and I'm passing the progress state to progress bar. (A Animated.View component that renders the current progress as width in style).
So basically, it will render every PROGRESS_BAR_TICK milliseconds due to setState. The problem I'm facing is - since JS is single threaded, if there's another event that takes the thread, or JS thread is slow on some low end devices, the progress bar will become junky.

Any suggestion to make it more smooth?

Comment: JS is single threaded but in RN the view runs on a separate thread, not to mention that setState is async... The issue might be not clearing the `setInterval` (for example in a `componentWillUnmount`) that will cause a memory leak / slow down...

Comment: You can use gif instead of animated.
It is workaround, however it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a setInterval could you start an `Animated.timing` animation to animate for the same duration as the story? If the user pauses the story you should be able to call `stop()` on the animation to halt it, then resume it again with the expected remaining duration.

Additionally, rather than animating the width of your progress bar, I'd encourage using either `scaleX` or `translateX` on the progress bar which can be run entirely on the native thread.

Here's a partial example missing the ways to trigger the `onStart` and `onPause` as I'm not sure what the rest of your component looks like.

```js
class Thing {
  _progressValue = new Animated.Value(0);

  onStart = (duration: number) => {
    this._animation = Animated.timing(this._progressValue, {
      duration: duration,
      toValue: 100,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  onPause = () => {
    if (this._animation != null) this._animation.stop();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{width: 100, height: 5, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
        <Animated.View style={{width: 100, height: 5, backgroundColor: 'red', transform: [{translateX: this._progressValue}]}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```